# SilverStripe best practice regarding pagetypes

Tags: php, silverstripe

Imagine you have two pagetypes: **Page** and **HomePage**. Obviously Page will serve as the basic page type for all pages and HomePage only for the homepage. For every basic page you want a custom header photo, and for homepage none.

What would be the ideal setup, as in best practice?

Page extends `sitetree` and has ImageUpload field for header

HomePage extends `Page` and disables the ImageUpload field for header

OR

Page extends `sitetree` and has ImageUpload field for header

HomePage extends `sitetree` without any additional CMS Fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another page type that inherits Page. Let's call it "BasicPage".

HomePage directly inherits Page.

BasicPage also directly inherits Page.

Then, attach the image "has_one" relationship to BasicPage.

I avoid creating pages of type "Page" in my site tree. I tend to mostly use "Page" as if it was an abstract type. The problem you'll encounter is that you'll stuff a lot of shared features in Page, and then one day, you'll need to create a new page type that has a very different look or set of features than most of the page types you've previously developed. When that'll happen, you'll be stuck with all the stuff inherited from Page and it will encumber both you and your application. Both you and your application will be slowed down.

Comment: I agree completely how you view and treat `Page`. This is my most desired solution, however, when adding a new page in the CMS, the pagetype Page is still there, while it shouldn't. You can remove this page option for basic users, but not for admin I believe..(?)

Comment: You can use: Config::inst()->update('Page','hide_ancestor','Page'); in the main "_config.php" file.

Comment: That's it, works like a charm! I now have the perfect page setup based entirely on your construction. Still feels a bit hacky but it's the best solution so far. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way I do it:

**Page.php**

Every `Page` and any pages that extend `Page` will inherit the Image upload field.

```
class Page extends SiteTree {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Image' => 'Image'
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', UploadField::create('Image'), 'Content');
        return $fields;
    }

}
```

**HomePage.php**

Then on any page where you don't want the image upload field just call `$fields->removeByName('Image');`

```
class HomePage extends Page {

    private static $db = array();

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->removeByName('Image');

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: This basically my current setup. Will this not pollute (in the smallest sense) the Database? Because HomePage still `has_one` `Image` although the field is removed.

Comment: Technically yes, but just referencing an ID isn't really much 'pollution' in the scheme of things. Lets say you have 6 different page types and you don't want to have the header image on just the HomePage only then the benefit of having the Image inherit on every page outweighs it in my opinion.

Comment: Well, if `Homepage` doesn't have anything in common with `Page`, why not just do `class HomePage extends SiteTree` ?? Of course your `HomePage_Controller` might extend `Page_Controller` for getting the global stuff you have there, or you put everything shared or global in Extensions and apply them to both, `Page` and `HomePage`

Comment: @wmk I honestly didn't know you could use the same controller for both pages. That does seem like a clean solution. One question remains: extending from SiteTree is not a terrible thing to do right?

Comment: I mean, extending multiple pagetypes from SiteTree that is.